# Integration of ODE with Python

Tags: python, ode

For a school project I have to integrate coupled ODE with Python.

None of my teachers can help me. I've tried with odeint et ode of `scipy.integrate`.

I get this error:

```
Excess work done on this call
```

I read that could be a stiffness issue but even if I change the number of steps, it does not work or bug.

Here my code:

```python
from scipy.integrate import ode
from numpy import *

pho=7.85*10**3     #kg/m3
E=2.1*10**11       #Pa
L=459*10**-3       #m
a=58*10**-3        #m largeur
b=35*10**-3        #m hauteur
n=25#int(input("Combien d'éléments voulez-vous?"))
nu=0.3

lp=L/n              #Longueur d'une poutre m
Iq=a*b**3/12        #m4
mp=pho*a*b*lp       #kg
J=mp*(lp**2+b**2)/12
#Initialisation des matrices Masse et Raideur
M=zeros(((n+1)*2,(n+1)*2))
K=zeros((2*(n+1),2*(n+1)))

Choix="1-Modèle masses concentrées\n2-Modèle Bernoulli\n3-Modèle Timoshenko"
print(Choix)
while 1:
    entree=3    #int(input('Quel modèle choisissez-vous?'))
    if entree not in [1,2,3]:
        print('\nMauvaise entrée!\n')
        print(Choix)
    else:
        break
if entree==1:
    Ks=array([[12,6*lp,-12,6*lp],[6*lp,4*lp**2,-6*lp,2*lp**2],
              [-12,-6*lp,12,-6*lp],[6*lp,2*lp**2,-6*lp,4*lp**2]])*E*Iq/lp**3
    Ms=array([[mp,0,0,0],[0,J,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]])
    M[-2,-2]=mp
    M[-1,-1]=J
elif entree==2:
        Ks=array([[12,6*lp,-12,6*lp],[6*lp,4*lp**2,-6*lp,2*lp**2],
              [-12,-6*lp,12,-6*lp],[6*lp,2*lp**2,-6*lp,4*lp**2]])*E*Iq/lp**3
        Ms=array([[156,22*lp,54,-13*lp],[22*lp,4*lp**2,13*lp,-3*lp**2],
                [54,13*lp,156,-22*lp],[-13*lp,-3*lp**2,-22*lp,4*lp**2]])*mp/420
else:
    #Corrections Timoshenko
    eta=(12+11*nu)/(10*(1+nu))
    phi=24*eta*Iq*(1+nu)/(a*b*L**2)

    #Matrice masse d'une poutre
    m1=312+588*phi+280*phi**2
    m2=(44+77*phi+35*phi**2)*lp
    m3=108+252*phi+175*phi**2
    m4=(26+63*phi+35*phi**2)*lp
    m5=(8+14*phi+7*phi**2)*lp**2
    m6=(6+14*phi+7*phi**2)*lp**2

    #Matrice masse d'un élément
    Ms=array([[m1,m2,m3,-m4],[m2,m5,m4,-m6],[m3,m4,m1,-m2],[-m4,-m6,-m2,m5]])*mp/840



    #Matrice raideur d'une poutre
    Ks=array([[12,6*lp,-12,6*lp],[6*lp,(4+phi)*lp**2,-6*lp,(2-phi)*lp**2],
                 [-12,-6*lp,12,-6*lp]
                 ,[6*lp,(2-phi)*lp**2,-6*lp,(4+phi)*lp**2]])*E*Iq/(lp**3*(1+phi))



#Définition des matrices masse et raideur
for k in range(0,2*n,2):
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            ligne=k+i
            colonne=k+j
            K[ligne,colonne]+=Ks[i,j]
            M[ligne,colonne]+=Ms[i,j]

invM=linalg.inv(M)
A=dot(invM,K)
W,u=linalg.eig(A)

L=[]

#Recheches des modes rigides
for i,freq in enumerate(W):
    if freq<=1:
        L+=[i]
L.sort()
u=delete(u,L,1)  #Suppresion des veceurs propres associés aux modes rigides
W=delete(W,L)    #suppresion des fréquences propres "nulles"
W=[W[i].real for i in range(len(W))]  #On transforme en réel (il y a des cas
#particulier ou on a des complexes avec valeurs imaginaires
#nulle ce qui posent problème pour l'utilisation de certaines fonction après)

#Récupération des fréquences propres
f=list(1/(2*pi)*sqrt(W))
indices=[]
ftri=sorted(f)
for iwtri,elt in enumerate(ftri):
    indices+=[f.index(elt)]       #Ne fonctionne pas si 2 fréquences identiques
utri=[u[:,ind].real for ind in indices]
#Vecteur en ligne cette fois (plus simple)
#utri[0] correspond au premier vecteur propre utri[1] au deuxieme etc..
#for i in range(len(wtri)):
#    print("Fréquence f",i+1,"=",f[i]," Hz",sep="")
#    print("Vecteur propre :\n",utri[i])
if len(f)>=3:
    print(ftri[0],'Hz ',ftri[1],'Hz ',ftri[2],'Hz')
#Recherche de la réponse spectrale
def imp(F0,T,t):
    if t<T/2:
        F=F0*sin(2*pi*t/T)
    else:
        F=0
    return F

a=print("Sur quel élément tapez vous?(Comrpis entre 1 et ",n+1,')',sep='')
a=1 #input()
position=int(a)


#Méthode modale

#Matrice de passage
U=array([[utri[j][i] for j in range(len(utri))] for i in range(len(utri[0]))])

#Matrice masse diagonalisée
Mdiag=dot(U.T,dot(M,U))
for i in range(len(Mdiag[0])):
    for j in range(len(Mdiag[0])):
        if Mdiag[i,j]>10**-10:
            Mdiag[i,j]=Mdiag[i,j]
        else:
            Mdiag[i,j]=0
#Matrice inverse
invMdiag=linalg.inv(Mdiag)

#Matrice raideur diagonalisée
Kdiag=dot(U.T,dot(K,U))
for i in range(len(Kdiag[0])):
    for j in range(len(Kdiag[0])):
        if Kdiag[i,j]>10**-5:
            Kdiag[i,j]=Kdiag[i,j]
        else:
            Kdiag[i,j]=0

#Matrice amortissement diagonale
xi=0.001
Bdiag=2*xi/(2*pi*ftri[0])*Kdiag

B=2*xi/(2*pi*ftri[0])*K
```

and the test of integration:

```python
import IntegrationNumerique as i
from scipy.integrate import ode,odeint
from numpy import *


def impact(F0,T,t):
    if t<T/2:
        F=F0*sin(2*pi*t/T)
    else:
        F=0
    return F


#Essai avec odeint
def derivOdeint(y,t):
    """Sans passer par les matrices diagonales"""
    dydt=zeros_like(y)
    milieu=int(len(y)/2)
    dydt[:milieu]=y[milieu:]
    F=zeros(2*(i.n+1))
    F[i.position-1]=impact(20.0,0.24*10**-3,t)
    C=dot(i.invM,F)-dot(dot(i.invM,i.B),y[milieu:])-dot(dot(i.invM,i.K),y[:milieu])
    dydt[milieu:]=C
    return dydt

def deriv2odeint(y,t):
    """Avec es matrices diagonales"""
    dydt=zeros_like(y)
    milieu=int(len(y)/2)
    dydt[:milieu]=y[milieu:]
    F=zeros(2*(i.n+1))
    F[i.position-1]=impact(20.0,0.27*10**-3,t)
    C=dot(dot(i.invMdiag,i.U.T),F)-dot(dot(i.invMdiag,i.Bdiag),y[milieu:])-dot(dot(i.invMdiag,i.Kdiag),y[:milieu])
    dydt[milieu:]=C
    return dydt

#Essai avec l'inegration orientee objet

def derivOde(t,y):
    """Sans passer par les matrices diagonales"""
    dydt=zeros_like(y)
    milieu=int(len(y)/2)
    dydt[:milieu]=y[milieu:]
    F=zeros(2*(i.n+1))
    F[i.position-1]=impact(20.0,0.24*10**-3,t)
    C=dot(i.invM,F)-dot(dot(i.invM,i.B),y[milieu:])-dot(dot(i.invM,i.K),y[:milieu])
    dydt[milieu:]=C
    return dydt

def deriv2ode(t,y):
    """Avec es matrices diagonales"""
    dydt=zeros_like(y)
    milieu=int(len(y)/2)
    dydt[:milieu]=y[milieu:]
    F=zeros(2*(i.n+1))
    F[i.position-1]=impact(20.0,0.27*10**-3,t)
    C=dot(dot(i.invMdiag,i.U.T),F)-dot(dot(i.invMdiag,i.Bdiag),y[milieu:])-dot(dot(i.invMdiag,i.Kdiag),y[:milieu])
    dydt[milieu:]=C
    return dydt
# use ``vode`` with "backward differentiation formula"
r = ode(derivOde).set_integrator('vode', 'bdf')

# Set the time range
t_start = 0.0
t_final = 0.64
delta_t = 1/12800
# Number of time steps: 1 extra for initial condition
num_steps = floor((t_final - t_start)/delta_t) + 1

# Set initial condition(s): for integrating variable and time!

r.set_initial_value([0 for j in range(104)], t_start)

# Additional Python step: create vectors to store trajectories
t = zeros((num_steps, 1))
sol = zeros((num_steps, 104))

t[0] = t_start



# Integrate the ODE(s) across each delta_t timestep
k = 1
while r.successful() and k < num_steps:
    r.integrate(r.t + delta_t)

    # Store the results to plot later
    t[k] = r.t
    for m in range(104):
        sol[k][m] = r.y[m]

    k += 1
```

Comment: Your code is long and you don't state what you expect to get or exactly what the error is. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well, the issue happens when I Iunch the solver, the first part is for explanation of what are needed to lunch the solver and the more common error is: "Excess work done wiht this call"

Comment: The code, while long, looks correct. You are solving `y''+Ay'+By=F` in dimension 140, which is a first order linear system of dimension 280, where the variation of eigenvalues can indeed lead to stiffness problems. Thus it is not a problem for this portal, but for scientific computing, http://scicomp.stackexchange.com, and less so also for mathematics, http://math.stackexchange.com. -- A hint could be "exponential methods", where the linear part is solved by explicit matrix exponentiation.

Comment: Instead of `for m in range(104): sol[k][m] = r.y[m]` you can use `sol[k,:]=r.y[:]` or `sol.k = r.y.copy()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is

```
M*u'' + B*u' + K*u = F
```

which you implement as `y' = - A*y - b` where

```
y = [ u']  A = [ invM*B  invM*K ]  b = [ invM*F ]
    [ u ]      [      I       0 ]      [      0 ]
```

The step size will depend on `A` in the form that  approximately `L*dt = 1e-3` for 4th or 5th order methods where `L` is the largest singular value of `A`. If that `L` is so large that `h<1e-8`, i.e., `L>1e5`, then to go from 0 to 1 you need in excess of `1e8` integration steps, which would trigger the mentioned error.

Typical tame differential equation take no more than a few dozen, and sometimes only a handful, of steps when using an adaptive step size scheme like Dormand-Price. This just to demonstrate the expectations on "resonable" and "excessive".

Since your system is linear, you can solve it using matrix exponentiation applied to the usual formula for the integration of a first order linear system with constant coefficients,

```
exp(A*t)*y(t) = y(0) + integral( exp(s*A)*F(s), s=0 to t )
```